# OS/IDE-agnostic method of storing snippets

Tags: cloud, code-snippets

I would like a way to store code snippets in a very straightforward way (to store and to retrieve).

I code sometimes at home sometimes at work or various other workspaces, so I'd like a repository that's in the cloud.  I would also like there to be an option for some kind of OS integration (via shortcut key perhaps; don't want to have to navigate to a webpage (snipplr) or an application (evernote) to retrieve the code).

Ideally something that combines the best of [Snipplr](http://snipplr.com/) and [Ditto](http://ditto-cp.sourceforge.net/).

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212634/best-application-for-storing-code-snippets), but I'm specifically concerned with a method that will work in OSX or Windows and be quicker to use within the OS than Evernote/Snipplr.  If something like that even exists

Comment: [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8886348/recommended-online-snippet-manager/16614380#16614380) might be of interest – very simiar question.

Comment: Oh, I want something like you describe, I even ask similar question before found yours http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444182/what-format-use-to-store-code-snippets-with-cross-platform-compatibility-in-mind

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Snippets](http://snippets.me/) is right for you. It is available as a native apps for Mac and Windows, supports sync out of the box and it's free. Also recently we released a feature called **[Distributors](http://snippets.me/distributors/)**. It allows you to re-use code snippets from Snippets in your IDE natively. Here are a couple of demos that demonstrates Snippets Distributors in action.

- [Snippets Distributor for Xcode](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=il4kE4diy0k)
- [Snippets Distributor for Visual Studio](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLcKLjzUX7M)

Disclaimer: I'm a founder of Snippets. Feel free to ask any question.