# Recommended online snippet manager

Tags: language-agnostic, code-snippets

I am looking for an online snippet manager for work, personal use and inspiration.

My primary needs are google/facebook login, fontification of various programming languages, privacy control, social network integration.

What's the recommendation?

Comment: I can see that one has voted for this question to be closed. Does this mean that it should have been posted on another forum?

Comment: I haven't voted, but I expect the vote for closure was because this sort of question invites subjective debate ("what's the best ...") instead of the programming Q&A ("why do I get this error message...") that the site is designed for.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew. I will consider this in the future. Where do you think that I should have asked - SuperUser?

Comment: This sort of general question is probably better suited to http://programmers.stackexchange.com/. However, that's a lower-traffic site than SO. Notice that, despite the vote to close, your question is still open. It's the ones that attract lots of low-quality subjective responses that are most likely to get closed.

Comment: I personally use [3Cols](https://3cols.com) as it's the only site that isn't slow like gists, offers enough categorisation options and stores all your snippets in the cloud for free. The only thing it charges for is sharing boards and that only costs $1.69 per month

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I enjoy using [GitHub Gists](https://gist.github.com/). It lets you version control your snippets, which is a nice benefit.

Comment: Also take a look at http://www.gistboxapp.com/ ; it works great with Github Gists, with a very nice user interface.

Comment: gistboxapp.com is nice, but there's no way to create a hierarchy or filter by multiple tags

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT:** This have become a Freemium service ([see pricing here](https://www.cacher.io/pricing/)), and changed name from Gistbox to [Cacher](https://www.cacher.io/).

For short snippets I use my editors snippet system. For bigger snippets I use Gists, which is also integrated in my editor through a plugin. In case your editor don't support Gists, you should look at http://www.gistboxapp.com/ which looks nice and cross platform.

Below is a screenshot. A demo video can be found at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLgyY6lqpsQ.

[image: GistBox Interface]

For passwords you should consider https://lastpass.com/ – that way your passwords is protected by... well, a (master)password. They are stored online, which means they're always accesible, and there's browser plugins for most browser, providing auto fill and auto login.

**Bonus tip:** If you find a snippet program, but does not like it, you may get a good idea about alternatives from alternativeto.net.

Answer (score 6):

**[snip2code](http://www.snip2code.com)** fits exactly all you needs.

Powerful search to get only useful code samples.

Highly recommended.

Answer (score 3):

I could suggest you to try [SnippLeaf.com](http://www.SnippLeaf.com) that designed by me for this kind of purposes. You could try and give me feedback what you like and dislike.
I created this not so long time ago because one of my favorite snippet manager closed and I already get used to it.
For me pastebin and gists I found too "heavy" and i concenrated on easy getting snippets.
I hope you will find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

http://pastebin.com looks like what you need

Answer (score 0):

I wrote my own tool for this.
See https://github.com/harish2704/templates
Demo on http://templates-harish2704.rhcloud.com
It can generate code by substituting parameter values on the template of code

Answer (score 0):

I made Snippeter, which will suite your need, you can see it in action by clicking on Live Preview on this link: codecanyon.net/item/snippeter-code-snippets-manager/6819365?ref=alenn

Answer (score 0):

CSnipp (http://csnipp.com) is a Code Snippet Manager that i build myself. You can store code snippets for your personal use, as well as share with the community. You can also fork and modify public snippets to your personal collection. Also its free for personal use and will always be free.

You can also browse and organize snippets under various languages, categories and tags.

Answer (score 0):

**Snippet Hero**

http://snippethero.com/

This is a very good bit of software